# In C++, how to overload a binary operator in a derived class?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, derived-class

I'm a C++ newbie and this is something I'm running into when doing some practice coding. Say I have a base class that looks like

```
class base {
public:
    base();
    friend base operator+(const base& lhs, const base& rhs) {
        base result;
        //some calculation
        return result;
    }
};
```

and a derived class

```
class derived : base {
public:
    derived();
    friend derived operator+(const derived& lhs, const derived& rhs) {
        // what to write here?
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to overload the + operator between two derived class objects? Essentially everything will be the same except I want

```
derived result;
```

instead of

```
base result;
```

in the first line, so that the constructor of the derived class takes care of some additional initialization of the object. It seems like a common polymorphism feature and I guess there must be an elegant way to do it, but I'm not sure how...

Thanks a lot!

Niko

Comment: Not obviously related to your problem but: why are you returning a reference to a local variable?

Comment: @zenith because it works.

Comment: @n.m. Can you add an answer to explain that more thoroughly?

Answer (score 2):

Implementing `operator+()` is riddled with problems when you have to deal
with a base class and derived classes.

The best I can think of is implementing a `virtual` `operator+=()` member
function that returns a reference to the object you are calling the
function on.

```
struct base
{
   // The usual other functions...
   virtual base& operator+=(base const& rhs) = 0;
};

// Provide an implementation in the base class that
// takes care of what can be taken care of in the base
// class.
// This is allowed even when the function is pure
// virtual.
base& base::operator+=(base const& rhs)
{
   // Do the needful.
   // Return a reference to this object.
   return *this;
}

struct derived : base
{
   virtual base& operator+=(base const& rhs)
   {
      // Add checks to make sure that rhs is of
      // derived type.

      // Call the base class implementation to take
      // care of updating base class data.
      base::operator+=(rhs);

      // Take care of updating the data of this object.

      // Return a reference to this object.
      return *this;
   }
};
```

Then you can use:

```
base* bPtr1 = new derived;
base* bPtr2 = new derived;
(*bPtr1) += (*bPtr2);
```

Comment: You are introducing runtime checks that may fail.

Comment: @n.m., yes. that's why I said "The best I can think of". I hope somebody has a better solution.

Comment: And it doesn't solve the posed problem, which is to avoid code duplication between base and derived.

Comment: @n.m., One can provide an implementation in the base class that takes care of the common code, and let the derived class implementations call it.

Comment: The question of making the operator virtual or not may be inportant, but it's orthogonal to the posted question. You can extract common code without making anything virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Binary operators in class hierarchies don't really work. It's OK to experiment and explore but satisfaction is not guaranteed.

One way to make some semblance of working code in this case is to make it into a template.

```
template <class P>
P operator+ (const P& p1, const P& p2);

class base {
  friend base operator+<> (const base& p1, const base& p2);
};

class derived : public base {
  friend derived operator+<> (const derived& p1, const derived& p2);
};

template <class P>
P operator+ (const P& p1, const P& p2)
{
  P p; 
  // do something
  return p;
}
```

It is best to put both classes and the operator+ in a namespace so that it does not conflict with other similar operators.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the `friend operator+` defined in `derived` needs to be identical to that defined in `base`, except the return type of the latter needs to be `derived`. One way to do this would be to define a constructor (maybe `private`) for `derived` that takes a `base` argument.

```
derived(base const& b)
: base(b)
// additional initialization for derived data members
{}
```

(or take `base` by value and `std::move` it to construct the `base` subobject)

Then, within `derived`

```
friend derived operator+(const derived& lhs, const derived& rhs) {
    return static_cast<base const&>(lhs) + static_cast<base const&>(rhs);
}
```

This will call `base`'s `operator+` and then construct a `derived` instance using the constructor defined above.